# Correct way of doing data validation when calling methods depending on validity of property

Tags: c#, wpf, idataerrorinfo

I have seen two ways of doing data validation in .Net 4.0.Currently Iam using IDataErrorInfo like this but the problem here is "this"  of IDataErrorInfo is called only when getter of Age property is called.I have some logic in the setter which is dependent on valid value of Age.

```
public int Age
    {
        get { return _age; }
        set
        {
            _age = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Age");
            //My methods to call when Age is valid

        }
    }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            string error = null;

            switch (columnName)
            {
                case "Age":
                    if (Age < 10 || Age > 100)
                      error="The age must be between 10 and 100";
                    break;
            }
            return error;

        }
    }
```

I can't call those methods as validation is not done when setter is called ,its done only when getter is called.Can somebody help me understand why its designed like that.In my opinion validation should be close to setter where value is assigned.

I am bound to change my implementation to this ,using Exception validation

```
public int Age
    {
        get { return _age; }
        set
        {
            if (value < 10 || value > 100)
                throw new ArgumentException("The age must be between 10 and 100");
            _age = value;

            //My methods to call when Age is valid
        }
    }
```

I am asking this question because the existing implementation is based on IDataErrorInfo in my project and there are lot of properties getting validated.Is there some solution which will let me keep IDataerrorInfo implementation and achieve the same I achieve from doing exception validation.

I do not want to throw exception on my property setters because its a design  guideline by microsoft

> Do not use exceptions for normal flow of control, if possible. Except
>   for system failures and operations with potential race conditions,
>   framework designers should design APIs so that users can write code
>   that does not throw exceptions. For example, you can provide a way to
>   check preconditions before calling a member so that users can write
>   code that does not throw exceptions.

and also I don't want to throw exceptions which I do not catch in my viewmodel code only.

This is my xaml

```
  <TextBox Text="{Binding Age, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,
      NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True,
    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean with getters but validation happens when you type in stuff therefore this[..] will be only called when setting the data. You seem a bit confused about all this. If you wish to throw validation error from ViewModel to View consider using INotifyDataErrorInfo.

Comment: @devhedgehog Its simple to test,put a break point at Getter of property,one at setter and one inside this[] and observe the sequence while debugging.Also INotifyDataErrorInfo is part of .Net 4.5.

Comment: Hmmm, I do not see much logic in getter being called first when I type in a letter in my TextBox for example. :) How have you configured the Binding between Age and your control?

Comment: @devhedgehog UpdateSourceTrigger="OnPropertyChanged",but binding syntax is not the question here.

Comment: Ok sure Bindng matters since Binding triggers validation. Could you post your XAML code please. What control are you using? Do you run into string to int parsing problems?

Comment: @devhedgehog I have added Xaml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binding first sets the value and then it calls the getter aaand then indexer is being called to validate. However your issue is that you wish the indexer to come first. That is not how wpf works.

Basically wpf gives you all freedom when using IDataErrorInfo therefore you have to implement all by yourself. Let me show you just an example:

```
public int Age
{
    get { return _age; }
    set
    {
        int oldVal = _age;
        _age = value;
        if(Validate("Age") == null)
        {
           // Do whatever you want

           OnPropertyChanged("Age");
        }
        else
        {
            // You can rollback value or not, it wouldnt matter...
            // PropertyChanged will not be fired!!!
            _age = oldVal;
        }
    }
}

public string this[string columnName]
{
    get
    {
       return Validate(columnName);
    }
}

public string Validate(string propertyName)
{
    string error = null;
    switch (propertyName)
    {
        case "Age":
            if (_age< 10 || _age > 100)
                error = "The age must be between 10 and 100";
    }

    return error;
}
```

Comment: cool..This helps a lot ..I will be calling Validate function in setters where I need to do some more things based on valid value and rest I can leave intact,,,So they will be eventually getting validated when indexer is called. ..Awesome.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, best way to achieve that is to call checking method in a setter and if it's validation result is false, don't set value to property and set some "InvalidState" flag. Otherwise set value and continue.

With InvalidState flag, you can throw [InvalidOperationException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception.aspx) when any method depending on object's state is called.

You can use basic **Boolean** value InvalidState or not or you can use **Enum** with different states (*NotInitialized*, *Valid*, *Invalid*, etc.) to manage code flow.

Comment: But in end you throw exception only.I want to avoid throwing exception with normal worklow of application,that was my question.

Comment: Throwing an exception is option, not a must. Having information about object's validity state, you can choose what you can do - repair object, ignore, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is due to your design rather than anything being done in .NET or by WPF.

From the sounds of it, you are immediately updating something based on the `OnPropertyChanged()` call in your code. I would not do this when working with UI-bound elements where users are involved as humans are the weak point in any system and you are always going to get invalid input from a user at some point.

You should rather be doing a deterministic update via a Save Command rather than a continuous update based on `OnPropertyChanged()`. The point of form validation is that you can deterministically validate an entire set of data before committing it to an underlying structure.

You should rather do something like add a private `Boolean` variable to store the validation state of the `Age` property and enable/disable the Save `Command` via the `ICommand.CanExecute()` method.

Comment: I agree but in my case requirement is  to do some calculations and show some results based on age automatically without any user action.

Comment: And also those kinds of design are very annoying where user has to click on save button so many times to find what he has filled wrong in a form with lots of fields.Those designs are good for developers not to end user.End user always like immediate response to its mistake so that he dont have go cycles of unsuccessful saves just for the sake of validation.

Comment: OKay, then you will need to use a custom way of validating (and not use IDataErrorInfo at all). I suggest that you use a bool variable to store valid/invalid state and only run the automatic code if in a valid state. You don't have to throw an Exception but UI objects won't reflect error (eg. red outline in textbox) unless you do. You could however have an image that changes based on the value of a public boolean using a Converter to convey an issue.

Comment: You don't need to click on the button to see there is a validation issue, but you have to raise `PropertyChanged` before `IDataErrorInfo.get` is invoked, which means changing the underlying value in the `Age.set` call, which you seem to want to avoid.

Comment: Yes,thanks..I will keep custom way as an option till I get a convincing answer.Actually this is a snapshot of big chunk of code.I am just looking if I can keep the IdataerrorInfo with minimal changes because lots of error templates and styles are already developed on that in my project.